# How to convert list to dictionary without messing up the sequence

Tags: python, python-2.7

1. when i used a function it messed up the sequence of my dictionary

   ```
   arr = ['loyd1', 'loyd2', 'loyd3', 'loyd4']
   list =  {k: 0 for k in arr}
   {'loyd1': 0, 'loyd3': 0, 'loyd2': 0, 'loyd4': 0}
   ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dictionaries: How to keep keys/values in same order as declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/dictionaries-how-to-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared)

Comment: Use ordereddict from collections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `OrderedDict()` to keep the same order in which the dictionary was created.

```
from collections import OrderedDict


arr = ['loyd1', 'loyd2', 'loyd3', 'loyd4']
dico =  OrderedDict((k, 0) for k in arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

please use OrderDict!

```
from collections import OrderDict
arr = ['loyd1', 'loyd2', 'loyd3', 'loyd4']
res = OrderedDict()
res = {i: 0  for i in arr}
print(res)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you do not want to import any module, simply do this:

```
arr = ['loyd1', 'loyd2', 'loyd3', 'loyd4']
dict={}
for k in arr: 
    dict[k]=0
```

Comment: That is no different from a dict comprehension, except for the fact that it's more verbose.